# How to avoid using allow_any_instance_of?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

Imagine we have following piece of code:

```
class A
  def create_server
    options = {
      name: NameBuilder.new.build_name
    }
    do_some_operations(options)
  end
end
```

To test such methods, I've used to use `allow_any_instance_of`:

```
it 'does operations' do
  allow_any_instance_of(NameBuilder).to receive(:build_name)
  # test body
end
```

But docs advise us not to use it [because of several reasons](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance). How then avoid `allow_any_instance_of`? I've came to only one solution:

```
class A
  def create_server
    options = {
      name: builder.build_name
    }
    do_some_operations
  end

  private

  def builder
    NameBuilder.new
  end
end
```

But with such approach code quickly becomes full of almost useless methods (especially when you actively using composition of different objects in described class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is difficult to test, it means you have a problem in your class design. In your case, when you are doing testing for specific method call on a specific class within a class you are testing like this:

```
allow_any_instance_of(NameBuilder).to receive(:build_name)
```

Your test know exactly how the method is implemented internally. Your classes should encapsulate the logic and hide it. You are doing exactly the opposite.

You *should not* be testing any internal method logic. Just test the behaviour. Give inputs and test the correctness of the output.

If you really want to test that method call on `NameBuilder` class, then inject that dependency and make your class more testable. This also follows OOP principles.

```
class A
  def create_server(builder)
    do_some_operations(name: builder.build_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: And then we should use double to fake builder object, right?

Answer (score 12):

In the absence of dependency injection as per [Uzbekjon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36643787/567863) (which I agree with) you could also consider stubbing out the call to `NameBuilder.new` so you can have direct control of the instance of `NameBuilder` under test:

```
class NameBuilder
  def build_name
    # builds name...
  end
end

class A
  def create_server
    options = {
      name: NameBuilder.new.build_name
    }
    do_some_operations(options)
  end

  def do_some_operations(options)
    # does some operations
  end
end

RSpec.describe A do
  let(:a) { described_class.new }

  describe '#create_server' do
    let(:name_builder) { instance_double(NameBuilder) }

    before do
      allow(NameBuilder).to receive(:new).and_return(name_builder)
    end

    it 'does operations' do
      # the first expectation isn't really part of what you seem
      # to want to test, but it shows that this way of testing can work
      expect(name_builder).to receive(:build_name)
      expect(a).to receive(:do_some_operations)
      a.create_server
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've eventually come to. It's especially handy when there are several objects creating in a cycle.